# What does "$<\!\!<\!\!<$" mean?

Tags: encryption, algorithm-design, notation

What does the symbol $<\!\!<\!\!<$ mean? It is normally followed by a number. An example: [image: here]

It would be appreciated if you could explain it in fairly basic terms.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

$$x<\!\!<\!\!<k$$ normally means cyclic rotation of a bit string $x$ to the left by $k$ bits.

Comment: Small side notes with regards to programming: 1) `>>>` in Java means shift right without sign extension (Java only has signed numbers, so the first bit is the sign). It's *not* rotation for that language. Other languages may have similar issues, check your operator 2) If you have a register / variable $x$ with $n$ bits then rotating left $k$ bits is the same as rotating right $n - k$ bits. And usually you can also rotate left $y \cdot n + k$ bits of course (if you rotate $n$ bits $n$ places then you're back where you started from) .